# INCREASE RANGE IN BY FOR-LOOP OR WHILE IN TERA DATA query

Tags: mysql, sql, scripting, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to run the query by rank in tera data which has millions of records. But I am not able to understand how to use for loop or while loop while incrementing by 10000 every time the query executes.

```
Right now I have hardcoded  QUALIFY **RANK(URT_ID) >= 10001** AND **RANK(URT_ID) <= 2000** but I need to increment the query by 10000 after every 10 minutes.

SEL RANK(URT_ID), a.* 
 FROM PP_ACCESS_VIEWS.DW_USER_RESTRICTION a 
 QUALIFY RANK(URT_ID) >= 10001 AND RANK(URT_ID) <= 2000
 ORDER BY URT_ID;
```

Comment: SQL is not a procedural language like that. You can script in another language which controls the loop, and then pass the query (which you control w a script) - or you can start learning BTEQ

Comment: Any kind of loop needs to be coded in a Stored Procedure (Your DBA probably didn't grant CREATE PROCEDURE right). But why do you want to do this?